# How to convert bytes to MB on disk

Tags: macos, file, byte

I have a file on my mac, when I clicked the `Get Info`, it showed as below
[image]

I wondered how 1,363,802bytes convert into 2.1MB ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "on disk" size measurement is telling you how much space your hard drive is using to store that file. The file is still only 1.36MB of data, but your hard drive has allocated 2.1MB of space to store it. Disks allocate storage space in units called "blocks" of a pre-defined size such as 4KB, so disks are often forced to allocate a little extra space in order to store files. The extra space is unused, but still counts of part of the file's size on disk.

Why is this image being allocated disk space almost 1.5X its size? Not sure!